# Assembling complex multidimensional dictionaries dynamically for JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift-dictionary

I'm trying to assemble some complex JSON like the following dynamically:

```
{
  "data": {
  "attributes": {
    "duration_sec": 200
  },
  "relationships": {
    "address": {
      "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "addresses"
      }
    }
  }
},
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "addresses",
      "id": null,
      "attributes": {
        "zip_code": "90210"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That is, I have an array of `Address` structs that I need to loop through to assemble the `relationships` and `included`. I would prefer if this were a dictionary, but I could also use `SwiftyJSON` to just assemble `JSON` object instead.

When I tried doing this myself, I kept having issues with ambiguity from the compiler, so I honestly don't know how to tackle this problem. I come from dynamic programming languages so am feeling just generally flummoxed by this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer that one without exact compiler error, but usually errors about ambiguity come from the fact that you're trying to create a heterogeneous dictionary and compiler is not able to infer it's type.

In case you want to create a json object like the one above and have use JSON(dictionary:) initializer you should declare a type of dictionary manually as **[String: AnyObject]**

example:

```
let exampleDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["one" : 1, "two": "two", "three": [1, 2, 3]]
```